# search conditions for multiple field values at a time in CASE statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `Table1` SET `col3` = 
CASE `col1`
WHEN 'ABC' THEN '2'
WHEN 'BCD' THEN '3'
ELSE '0'
END
```

In this, can I have condition for both col1 and col2 to set the value for col3 like if I have

```
      col1 = 'ABC' AND col2 = '123'
```

then I want to set

```
    col3 = 2 and col1 = 'ABC' AND col2 = '124' then set col3 = '4'
```

and how to set multiple column values at a time? Suppose here if I have col4 also then how to set both col3 and col4 values depending on the col1 and col2 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 SET col3 = 
CASE 
WHEN col1 = 'ABC' AND col2 = '123'
THEN '2'
ELSE '0'
END
,
col4 = 
WHEN col1 = 'ABC' AND col2 = '124'
THEN 'x'
ELSE '0'
END
```

Updating multiple columns, and multiple conditions in when clause.